# Powershell - How can I do a live Active directory search using a dropdown menu

Tags: winforms, powershell, drop-down-menu, powershell-2.0

It's probably an easy questions for experienced guys like you, but how can I do a live Active Directory search for a user name in a dropdown menu take the selected result and pass the value to `$var`

Here is my from and my two dropdown menu, I want the `manager` dropdown to do a lookup in my Active Directory based on the string I entered. I.e. if I enter `Macdonald` the dropdown items will show all Macdonald in my AD for first name or last name.

```
function GenerateForm {

[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownLabel2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDown2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox


$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.Text = "User Creation software"
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 400
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 200
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size

$DropDownArray = "Site1" , "Site2" , "Site3"

$DropDown2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(125,80)
$DropDown2.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(150,27)
$dropdown2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$dropdown2.TabIndex = 5
$dropdown2.Name = "dropdown2"
$Form1.Controls.Add($DropDown2)

$DropDownLabel2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownLabel2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(50,80)
$DropDownLabel2.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(50,27)
$DropDownLabel2.Text = "Manager:"
$Form1.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel2)

$DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(125,55)
$DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(150,27)
$dropdown.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$dropdown.TabIndex = 4
$dropdown.Name = "dropdown1"

$DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(50,58)
$DropDownLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(50,27)
$DropDownLabel.Text = "Location:"

$Form1.Controls.Add($DropDown)
$Form1.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel)

ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray) {
$DropDown.Items.Add($Item) | Out-Null
}

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
} #end of function
GenerateForm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a live update you need to update the list when the text in the dropbox is modified. There are at least 2 events thats triggered when you write in it: `TextUpdate` and `KeyPress` . Choose ONE.  I'd suggest `TextUpdate` since it reacts after the text is changed, while `KeyPress` reacts before. You can add a eventlistener using e.g.:

```
$DropDown2.add_TextUpdate({ Write-Host "TextUpdate. Updated text is: $($Dropdown2.Text)" })
```

In the scriptblock you need to run a function that queries the DC, but this question is not tagged with ADSI, AD, LDAP etc. so that's another question.

**Be aware** that this will run the query EVERY time you change a letter which is causing extra load on the DC. E.g. if you want to write "Mark", it will have searched minimum 4 times before you are done writing.

I'd suggest using a textbox with a search-button instead to minimize unecessary traffic.

Comment: That's a good point, I will take your advice for the search botton. And I will also create a new question for the AD search. Thanks @Grainer, your help is price less, for any other things there is M@stercards :P